# How could I access my VM in my host machine (By different IP)?

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04, vmware, vmware-workstation

I want to access the virtual machine IP in the host (by ping or curl or something), but it is not ok. How could I make it?

The host machine is a win10 PC.

A virtual machine using **VMware workstation 15, Ubuntu 16.04 server**. It has IP address `192.168.178.138` and `10.0.0.11`. I can access the 192.168.178.138, but cannot access 10.0.0.11. (no matter ping or curl...)

All are **NAT** mode in VMware Workstation.

Now I have a web application running on 10.0.0.11:80. How could I access it in my host machine.

> Btw I have another VM with `192.168.178.39` and `10.0.0.31`, and this VM can access the 10.0.0.11:80 by curl.

I can show the topo as below.

[image: the topo]

(A little Chinese but it won't affect reading, just ignore it)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now I solve this question by myself.

It seems that you cannot use the Host-only mode (Actually I can only use this mode...).

1. You need to set the virtual interface in your host PC (The IP, gateway, or anything else...);
2. Then you need to set in the VMWare workstation, set it to use speical lan (VM net 2 for me);
3. Then you can access it from the host machine and other vm, maybe you need to search something like `NAT translation in VMWare workstation` to access your web application deployed in the VM from outer network.

That's what I do, now I can access my horizon dashboard in the browser (The Ubuntu server don't have any browser... T-T sad ...)

[Settings Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ped73.png)